# Remove Column from a GridView (VB.NET 2008)

Tags: vb.net, gridview, oledbconnection

{VB.NET 2008 using Northwind Microsoft Database}
How can i remove a column with name like id only from the demogrid ? (Without using sql code)

```
    Dim strSQL As String = _
     "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=1"

    Try
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, _
          My.Settings.OleDbConnectionString)

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            adapter.Fill(ds, "ProductInfo")


            demoList.DisplayMember = "ProductName"
            demoList.ValueMember = "ProductID"

            demoGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("ProductInfo")

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the column you don't like

```
GridViewName.Columns.Remove("ColumnName")
```